# PHP Directory-specific Content and Redirects

Tags: php, algorithm

I have this code

```
$pageEx = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $pageLn = count($pageEx);
            $currentdir = $pageEx[$pageLn - 2];

            switch($currentdir) {
                case "admin":
                    if(!$this->loggedIn) {
                        header("Location: index.php");
                    }
                    if($this->userData['user_level'] < 3) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php");
                    }
                break;

                case "mgmt":
                    if(!$this->loggedIn) {
                        header("Location: index.php");
                    }
                    if($this->userData['user_level'] < 2) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php");
                    }
                break;

                case "user":
                    if(!$this->loggedIn) {
                        header("Location: index.php");
                    }
                    if($this->userData['user_level'] < 1) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php");
                    }
                break;
            }
```

and was just wondering whether there's a shorter way I could do it?
The code works, but its a lot of code for something so simple.
It checks the directory they're in then if they aren't the right user_level it redirects them to the index page.

**Edit: Done it.**

```
$pageEx = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $pageLn = count($pageEx);
            $currentdir = $pageEx[$pageLn - 2];


            /*
                User Level Required => Directory
            */
            $permissions = array(
                1 => 'user',
                2 => 'mgmt',
                3 => 'admin'
            );

            foreach($permissions as $perms => $key) {
                if(!$this->loggedIn) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php");
                }
                if($currentdir == $key) {
                    if($perms > $this->userData['user_level']) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why parse the `!$this->loggedIn` in every iteration of the foreach? Move it outside and before the foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
$pageEx = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pageLn = count($pageEx);
$currentdir = $pageEx[$pageLn - 2];

if(!$this->loggedIn) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$permissions = array(
    'admin' => 3,
    'mgmt' => 2,
    'user' => 1,
);

if($this->userData['user_level'] < $permissions[$currentdir]) {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

**UPDATE:** I just noticed you wanted to do a LESS THAN... so I updated the code to reflect the way it works in your code.

Comment: Almost. I need the login check each time, as this script runs even when they're not logged in.

Comment: Th advantage of doing it his way is you can add to the array without having to touch much code. Or you can easily convert it to reading a database etc. Glad you liked it!

Comment: I've managed to take the way your code worked and manipulated it to fit my needs.I've edited my first post if you would like to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You might cringe at this, but you could get it down to 6 lines if the long if statement doesn't bother you...

```
$pageEx = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$currentdir = $pageEx[count($pageEx) - 2];

if(!$this->loggedIn)
    header("Location: index.php");
elseif(($currentdir == "admin" && $this->userData['user_level'] < 3) || ($currentdir == "mgmt" && $this->userData['user_level'] < 2) || ($currentdir == "user" && $this->userData['user_level'] < 1))
    header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Note the change to an elseif because--and correct me if I'm mistaken--either the user is not logged in and gets redirected to index.php or the user is logged in and might get directed to ../index.php. If they were separate if statements, it seems there could end up being two Location headers.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've figured out a way I like, check my question post.

Comment: Looks good. How come you can't put the $this->loggedIn check outside of the loop, though?